# How To Pass Id That doesn't Match Any Document in Collection - MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

When i try to insert a new document using the method

```
db.collection.findOneAndReplace({_id : NaN}, {"name" : "department"},  {    upsert : true, returnNewDocument: true })
```

I'm using `{_id : NaN}` here so that no document matches

Instead of creating a document with a valid id it creates a document whose id is `NaN`

```
{
  _id : NAN,
  name: "department"
```

}

How can i get a valid id? or is there any mistake in my method parameters?

Comment: Seems like you're using the wrong method to do what you want. Why using `findOneAndReplace` and intentionally make it so it won't find one? You want to insert a record?

Comment: If you want it not to replace anything why are you using upsert? Why not just add the record?

Comment: _id in mongodb is a unique identification for the row. It is preferred not to play with it or change its value unless you have some strict requirement. You should insert the record directly to get the valid _id.

Comment: I'm devoloping a application in elixir... In some examples  i found this method `{:ok, user} = Mongo.find_one_and_replace(:mongo, "users", %{}, changeset_new_user.changes, [return_document: :after, upsert: :true])` to insert a new document where `%{}` is the filter which always returns all the documents in the collection... Then the first document in  the collection is replaced by current new document... so i used `{_id: NaN}` which doesn't return any documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `{_id : {$exists: false}}`, so that it will match none of the documents. However it's still a weird operation as it makes no sense to use `upsert` for `insert` operation only.

I'd recommend you to try [insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) if you need a new document and in case the document may exist and you need to update it (or instead create a new one) - do [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).